# adding custom js libraries to webstorm / phpstorm

Tags: libraries, phpstorm, webstorm, head.js

so i just started using webstorm & phpstorm. i use head.js is almost all my larger javascript apps. in my main.html file i use a script tag to load head.js, and pass all the other js files i need loaded into it. when my real app.js file is loaded i use the `head.ready` method to auto run my init code.

```
head.ready(function(){
   //code here
});
```

well jslint/jshint cannot resolve the head object to anything so it throws an error in all my files. i did some research and i found under: `file >> settings >> javascript >> libraries` you can enable libraries into the global or local context of your project.

i enabled this for jQuery (a default choice) and it works great! they dont have a predefined option for head.js, so i tired to add it myself. under the add menu you browse for the file and "attach" it. after doing this process a few times (i tied a few different scopes) i'm still having no luck.

*"help me stackoverflow, you're my only hope!"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a jslint/jshint config issue more than a "libraries" issue. From what I understand, defining libraries simply helps provide autocomplete for dynamically loaded scripts.